# Check for validation Errors in Silverstripe Form

Tags: php, validation, silverstripe

i have a Form that is being displayed as a modal. This modal is only being displayed if the user clicks the corresponding link.
The Form itself works as expected.

There is only one major issue I am experiencing. Whenever the form is invalid the RequiredFields Validator kicks in, the user is being directed back and that's it.

In this scenario I want to display the modal immediately but i can't find a way to check for Validation Errors.

Is there someone with the same issue who managed to solve it or is there someone how can help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i had following solution for a boostrap site i did some time ago. I didn't replace the whole page but only the modal:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('form[data-async]').on('submit', function(event) {
var $form = $(this);
var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));

$.ajax({
type: $form.attr('method'),
url: $form.attr('action'),
data: $form.serialize(),

success: function(data, status) {
$target.html(data);
}
});

event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

This replaces the content with the actual response. found it [here](https://gist.github.com/ThomasWallace/4680256)

In the template:

```
<!-- Bootstrap trigger to open modal -->
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#rating-modal">Write a Review</a>

<div class="hide fade modal" id="rating-modal">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h2>Your Review</h2>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
<!-- The async form to send and replace the modals content with its response -->
<form class="form-horizontal well" data-async data-target="#rating-modal" action="/some-endpoint" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<!-- form content -->
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Be sure to check in your php code with [Director::is_ajax()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Director.html#_is_ajax) if you have an ajax request or not to respond with the right template.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I do like the async approach. I will give it a try and get back if it works for me.

Comment: I am using RecaptchaFields as well. Turns out that this async approach is more complicated than i thought. Can''t get backend Validation to kick in after submitting the form.

Comment: I prefer http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/camspiers/honeypot honeypot field for spam protection. maybe it's enough for you, too